# LEFT JOIN из нескольких таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть простая переменная:

```
$productId = 1;
```

Также есть 3 таблицы.

**Product_Document** (словарь ProductID - DocumentID)

```
| ProductID | DocumentID |
|-----------+------------|
| 1         | 20         |
```

**Document_IndicNozology** (словарь DocumentID - NozologyCode)

```
| DocumentID | NozologyCode |
|------------+--------------|
| 20         | B24..        |
```

И таблица **Nozology**, где хранится нужная информация

```
| NozologyCode | NozologyContent  |
|--------------+------------------|
| B24..        | Описание болезни |
```

Возможно ли с помощью `LEFT JOIN` и переменной `$productId` в один запрос получить нужную информацию из третьей таблицы? Я пробовал получить данные следующим образом:

```
$request = "SELECT * FROM Nozology 
LEFT JOIN Document_IndicNozology ON Document_IndicNozology.NozologyCode = Nozology.NozologyCode 
LEFT JOIN Product_Document ON Product_Document.DocumentID = Document_IndicNozology.DocumentID 
WHERE Product_Document.ProductID = $productId";
```

Но это к сожалению ничего не дало (не возвращается никаких данных).

Comment: Порядок таблиц неверен. Должно быть `Product_Document LEFT JOIN Document_IndicNozology LEFT JOIN Nozology`.

Comment: А в PHP можно в строке прямо использовать переменную? Т.е. в `$request` попадет уже отформатированная строка, `$productId` заменится на реальное значение этой переменной?

Comment: @Akina То есть чтобы получить информацию из третьей таблицы, мне нужно использовать следующий код: `$request = "SELECT * FROM Nozology LEFT JOIN Product_Document ON Product_Document.DocumentID = Document_IndicNozology.DocumentID LEFT JOIN Document_IndicNozology ON Document_IndicNozology.NozologyCode = Nozology.NozologyCode WHERE Product_Document.ProductID = $productId";`? Я пробую использовать этот запрос, но всё равно ничего не приходит.

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin можно, но в SQL запросе такую строку использовать нельзя

Comment: @Win_D надо использовать **тот порядок таблиц, который приведен в комментарии Akina**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение вопроса:

```
$request = "SELECT * FROM Product_Document 
LEFT JOIN Document_IndicNozology ON Document_IndicNozology.DocumentID = Product_Document.DocumentID 
LEFT JOIN Nozology ON Nozology.NozologyCode = Document_IndicNozology.NozologyCode 
WHERE Product_Document.ProductID = $productId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Общие рекомендации по решению вопросов такого плана.

1. Забыть про РНР
2. Поставить себе phpmyadmin
3. тренироваться на кошках, пока не получится идеально работающий запрос
4. Только после этого взять полученный SQL, и аккуратно скопировать в РНР код.

Пункт 3 также должен быть разбит на подпункты.
у нас три таблицы и два джойна.
- Значит сначала делаем три ПРОСТЫЕ селекта с WHERE в каждую таблицу по отдельности, и убеждаемся, что данные там есть.
- После этого делаем джойн первых ДВУХ таблиц, и смотрим, вернул ли но что- либо
- после этого делаем джойн вторых двух таблиц, и смотрим то же самое
- и только после этого делаем джойн всех трех

Момент, на котором этот план перестанет работать, покажет причину, по которой не работает весь запрос. В этом случае надо проверять конкретные данные в таблицах.